# Unable to grab phone number and address

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've scraped title and website link but I fail to pull phone number and address. How can I get them?

Here's what I have:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.constructionplacements.com/top-construction-companies-in-india/'
req=requests.get(url)

soup =BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')

for h4 in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='h4' and re.search(r'^\d+\.',tag.text)):
    title=h4.text
    website=h4.find_next('a')['href']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this:

Note: Not all companies have a phone number.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def extractor(search_for: str) -> list:
    return [
        p.getText() for p in soup if p.getText(strip=True).startswith(search_for)
    ]


url = 'https://www.constructionplacements.com/top-construction-companies-in-india/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml").select(".post p")

phone_numbers = extractor("Phone")
addresses = extractor("Address")

print(len(phone_numbers), len(addresses))
```

Output:

```
62 70
```

What this does

```
def extractor(search_for: str) -> list:
    return [
        p.getText() for p in soup if p.getText(strip=True).startswith(search_for)
    ]
```

is basically iterating over all elements of `<p>` in the `post` section and if `p.getText()` starts with a given phrase `search_for` it grabs that element `p` and extracts its text value.

The logic works with pargraphs that start either with `Phone` or `Address`.

Comment: `p.getText() for p in soup if p.getText(strip=True).startswith(search_for)` can you explain little bit this line so others people can get help from your answer. How it's exactly knowing where phone number and address located?  how it's avoiding to grab others text before and after phone number and address?

Comment: @boyenec I've udpated the answer.